# How can i select elements right after a :first-child in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to select a section on a table by making its border thicker on a selected area, so I need to change the border on specifics cells to get something like this.

[image]

this is my best try for the upper one.
every selected cell has a "selected" class, and if there is a selected cell, the row has a selected class too. I hope you get it ;)

```
.table tr.selected:first-child td.selected{
    border-top-width:5px;
    border-top-color:#000;
}
```

is it possible?

Comment: so you are targeting the next sibling of the first child?

Comment: im targeting all children with selected class of the first element.

Comment: it would be helpful to see your HTML code

Comment: I edited the post. hope it clear your doubts

Comment: I dont understand why you need the :first-child selector?

Comment: I think your best bet would be the nth-child() selector. Can you post your whole code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not restricted with these specific class names, you can add a custom class to cells of the last selected row. If you cannot modify the HTML, you can try to add the custom classes with JavaScript.

```js
var selectedRows = document.querySelectorAll('tr.selected');
selectedRows[selectedRows.length-1].classList.add('last-selected-row');
```

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  table tr td{
    border: 1px solid #e2e4e8;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  table td.selected{
    background-color: #cae5cd;
  }

  table tr.selected td.selected:first-child{
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    border-right: none;
  }

  table tr.selected td.selected:last-child{
    border-right: 3px solid black;
    border-left: none;
  }

  table tr.selected td.selected + td:not(.selected){
    border-left: 3px solid black;
  }

  table tr:not(.selected) + tr.selected td.selected{
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e4e8;
  }

  table tr.last-selected-row td.selected{
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>far east</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>USD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>pol</td>
      <td>pod</td>
      <td>USD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="selected">
      <td class="selected">VALENCIA MADRID</td>
      <td class="selected">BRISBANE</td>
      <td>USD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="selected">
      <td class="selected">VALENCIA MADRID</td>
      <td class="selected">Melbourne</td>
      <td>USD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="selected">
      <td class="selected">VALENCIA MADRID</td>
      <td class="selected">SYDNEY</td>
      <td>USD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>VALENCIA MADRID</td>
      <td>Chongoing</td>
      <td>USD</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

The `padding` and the border styles I have added in the snippet are just for demo purpose.